# ASP.NET application - ideas on how to speed it up

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

This is a very general question, so I won't be providing any code as my project is fairly large.

I have an ASP.NET project, which I've been maintaining and adding to you for a year now. There's about 30 pages in total, each mostly having a couple of gridview's and SqlDataSource's, and usually not more than 10-15 methods in the codebehind. There is also a fairly hefty LINQ-to-SQL dbml file - with around 40-50 tables.

The application takes about 30-40 seconds to compile, which I suppose isn't too bad - but the main issue is that when deployed, it's slow at loading pages compared to other applications on the same server and app pool - it can take around 10 seconds to load a simple page. I'm very confident the issue isn't isolated to any specific page - it seems more of a global application issue.

I'm just wondering if there are any settings in the web.config etc I can use to help speed things up? Or just general tips on common 'mistakes' or issues developers encounter than can cause this. My application is close to completion, and the speed issues are really tainting the customer's view of it.

Comment: First, ensure that you specify `debug="false"` (as pointed out by others.) If that doesn't help, then start up a profiler, see what's taking the most time, and then fix that. Repeat until the site is fast enough.

Comment: Also you can check if there are any nested loops. I guess you can use PLINQ.

Comment: "Slow when deployed" means that it's fast in your development integrated server? If this is so, then something's wrong with your IIS. If not (slow in dev too), you can easily debug it and find all bottlenecks.

Comment: What can you tell us about your production server?  How does the hardware and network compare to your development environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first step find out source of the problem, either application or database side.

**Application side:**

Start by enabling trace for slow pages and see size of ViewState, sometimes large ViewState cause slow page load.

**Database side:**

Use Sql Profiler to see what exactly requires a lot of time to get done

Useful links:

- [How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx)
- [Improve ASP.NET Performance By Disabling ViewState And Setting Session As ReadOnly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2007/08/16/improve-asp-net-performance-by-disabling-viewstate-and-setting-session-as-readonly.aspx)
- [How to Identify Slow Running Queries with SQL Profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/)

Answer (score 2):

Most common oversight probably: don't forget to turn off debugging in your web.config before deploying.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

A few others:

- Don't enable session state or viewstate where you don't use it
- Use output caching where possible, consider a caching layer in general i.e. for database queries (memcached, redis, etc.)
- Minify and combine CSS
- Minify javascript

Answer (score 0):

**What to do now:**

1. Look at page load in Firebug or Chrome developer tools.  Check to make sure you're not sending a huge payload over the wire.
2. Turn on trace output to see how the server is spending its time.
3. Check network throughput to your server.

**How to avoid this in the future:**

Remember that speed *is* a feature.  If your app is slow as a dog, customers can't help but think it sucks.  This means you want to run your app on "production" hardware as soon as you can and deploy regularly so that you catch performance problems as they're introduced.  It's no fun to have an almost-done app that takes 10 seconds to deliver a page.  Hopefully, you get lucky and can fix most of this with config.  If you're unlucky, you might have some serious refactoring to do.

For example, if you've used ViewState pretending it was magic and free, you may have to rework some of that dependency.

> Keep perf on a short leash.  Your app will be snappy, and people will
>   think you are awesome.